# MakeIndex and \alph

Tags: page-numbering, indexing

Whilst reading the [manual for MakeIndex](http://mirror.ctan.org/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.pdf) I stumbled upon:

> *MakeIndex* assumes that all page numbers are either arabic or lower-case
>   roman numerals; it assumes that pages numbered with roman numerals
>   precede those numbered with arabic numerals.

and wondered... how can I lift this restriction? Specifically: how can I tell MakeIndex to *not* verify the page numbering format?

For instance, if I have an index entry on an `\alph` page.

I'm open to suggestions regarding alternative indexing preprocessors, but they should work with `hyperref` (ruling out `xindy` if memory serves).

Comment: It's a limitation of MakeIndex, yes. Why isn't `xindy` a choice?

Comment: As far as I remember `xindy` had no support for `hyperref`... please do correct me if I'm wrong! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following `test.tex` document compiles perfectly and all the page references have their hyperlink:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[program=texindy]

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
abc\index{abc}

\mainmatter
xyz\index{xyz}

abc\index{abc}

\newpage
abc\index{abc}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{alph}

\appendix
abc\index{abc}

\newpage
abc\index{abc}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Of course `imakeidx` is not necessary, I used it just for doing everything in one step, running

```
pdflatex --shell-escape test
```

Pages with alphabetic numbering are sorted after arabic numbered ones, which come after roman numbered ones, but I guess it's possible to customize Xindy's behavior.

On the other hand, the same result is obtained with MakeIndex.

Comment: This, sir, is one great answer :)

Comment: @egreg: Why texindy?  In other words, why not xindy?

Comment: @Sony It's a script that calls xindy after some common initializations relative to LaTeX usage

Comment: @egreg: Thanks.  I will ask a (detailed) question to get a more detailed answer. :)